# how to select if condition does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to select all `Out_No` where this condition `does not exist`

```
(event_type = 'COMMENT_CHANGE' and COMMENTS LIKE 'Cause:%')
```

sample query

```
select 
       Out_no
from TableA
Where Out_no > '12345'
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519266/not-exists-in-the-same-table/4519285#4519285).

```
select out_no,
from TableA
where out_no > '12345'
and out_no not in
         ( select 
                  out_no
             from TableA
            where event_type = 'Comment_change' 
              and comments like 'Cause%'
         )
Order by out_no desc
```

hope it helps others.